# Move a row of a table.el table

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I have this org-mode table, which apparently is a `table.el` table:

```
+-----+------+
| Test|Foobar|
+-----+------+
|     |      |
+-----+------+
```

When I hit `Tab` in any cell, emacs tells me: `Use ‘C-c '’ to edit table.el tables` . Hitting `C-c '` opens a buffer in `Table-mode`, in which I can edit that table. However, calling `org-move-table-row-down` in that buffer, with the cursor on the cell containing 'Test', only results in the message `user-error: Cannot move row further`. `C-h b` does not list any key binding to any function that sounds like it moves a row down.

When I leave `Table-mode` (by hitting `C-c '` again) and then in plain org-mode call `org-move-table-row-down` again, I get the same error.

Is there a way of moving rows of `table.el` tables? Alternatively: Can I somehow convert that table to a plain org-mode table, on which I can use the usual org-mode table editing functions?

Comment: M-x org-table-convert  convert to a usual org-mode table when the point is in the table.

Comment: Unfortunately, `org-table-convert` is very simple-minded: in particular, it mangles the table above.

Comment: It's just text so you can use e.g. cut-and-paste to cut a row and paste it somewhere else.